# In graphql, filter on multiple values on the same property and paginate

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

I have got the following need :  Using the graphql syntax, filter a collection according to multiple values on the same property and paginate the results

Considering the following entity ...

```
/** ... APIResource annotations
 */
class RssFeed {
    /** ... APIProperty annotations
    */
    private $category;

    /** ... APIProperty annotations
    */
    private $url; 

    // ... getters
    // ... setters
}
```

I want to filter the collection of `RssFeed` which `category` property is "CategoryA" or "CategoryB" and paginate the results.

According to my knowledge, graphql does not allow to write a syntax similar to

```
rssfeed(category: ["CategoryA","CategoryB"]) 
{
    edges { node {
    url,
    category
    } }
}
```

So I need to separate the search operation using distinct graphql queries (in the body) like

```
rssFeedsA: rssfeed(category: "CategoryA") 
{
    edges { node {
    url,
    category
    } }
},
rssFeedsB: rssfeed(category: "CategoryB") 
{
    edges { node {
    url,
    category
    } }
}
```

But, I can't paginate the global results.

So, my question, is there any solution to filter on multiple values and paginate ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the confusion came from, but there's nothing stopping you doing your first example, you just need the type of the category input to be an array of Strings. Though i'd personally rename it to `categories`:

```
type Query {
    rssFeed(
        first: Int, 
        last: Int, 
        before: String, 
        after: String, 
        categories: [String!]
    ): SomeConnection
}
```

How you'd actually implement the the resolver logic to make it work is up to you, but it's likely to be only slightly different to how you'd do it for a single category

Comment: As I can't modify my entity, I need to create a custom api-platform filter  ?